# Is there any reason not to host a software repository with a standard web hosting service?

Tags: repository

I have webspace and I was thinking of setting up a git repository on it.

If I am developing software and I want to host a repository (CVS, SVN, git, etc) online, is there any reason not to use a standard web hosting provider (GoDaddy, etc) to do this?
I'm thinking in terms of security, reliability, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for not using a standard-company is that usually shell-access is needed to setup a Version Control System (VCS). Many providers don't give shell access on normal webspaces.

When you are developing open-source software I'd recommend hosting at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/), [github](https://github.com), [Google Code](http://code.google.com) or similar providers, as your code is public there, you will get an issue tracker and several other tools that may help you. On github for example adding more developers to your project is very easy.

When you are developing closed-source software you still can use github, this gives you the same advantages as mentioned above, but of course it costs you a few bucks a month. Open-Source projects are free.

So while there is no real reason to not use standard hosting providers there are good reasons to use a company dedicated on hosting code.

As you asked especially for security: github (I use it as an example, as I host my code there as well) gives you a [full list of information of what they do to ensure your code is safe](https://help.github.com/articles/github-security).